# erro no PHP quando muda de host

Tags: php, if, extensão

Boa tarde, eu utilizava um host online com php 7 e eu tinha a seguinte sintaxe

```
if(!saber_se_não_existe) {}
```

Sempre funcionou tanto assim quanto assim

```
if(saber_se_existe) {}
```

Tanto que refiz meu código inteiro trocando o EMPTY e o ISSET por este que ficou show mas hoje fui rodar em PHP localhost e este não funcionam, precisei mudar tudo para !empty ou empty e o PHP também é o 7, o que permite isso é alguma extenção? se sim, podem me informar qual? eu em localhost utilizei o PHPDESKTOP tanto o 47 quando o 53 dão o mesmo erro mas online não.

## edit

Tenho uma condição IF que verifica se uma variável foi setada que no caso se utiliza o isset e para saber se está vazia o empty, ou seja

```
$existe = true;
$nao_existe = false;
```

Logo

```
if(empty($existe)) {
// não mostra pois existe
}
```

e

```
if(isset($nao_existe)) {
// mostra pois existe, mesmo estando vazia
}
```

assim como posso utilizar o

```
unset(variavel_com_ou_sem_valor);
$varialvel_com_ou_sem_valor ? false : true;
```

existem ínumeras formas de se fazer, tanto que descobri o exemplo la de cima, que basta fazer

```
if($variavel_com_ou_sem_valor) {
// se tem mostra
}
```

e

```
if(!$variavel_com_ou_sem_valor) {
// se não tem mostra
}
```

só isso, porém, meu servidor online, tanto em um emuloador de android quanto um shared de internernet, funcionam este último, mas no meu localhost com [PHPDESKTOP](https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop) da

> undefined index

Comment: eu achei seu exemplo incompleto. saber_se_existe é uma contante? nao da pra entender realmente o que vc quer

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o seu exemplo?

Comment: @KayoBruno não é uma constante, na verdade é só saber se existe a variável ou não, a sim, claro, irei reformular

Comment: @KarlZillner vou refazer e colocar algo melhor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os seus ambientes estão com configurações diferentes de `error reporting`.

Se você olhar o `php.ini` ou `phpinfo()` de cada um, vai ver duas configurações:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL # ou outro valor
display_errors = true # ou false
```

A combinação dos valores possíveis nessas duas configurações faz com que alguns servidores reclamem de mais aspectos do seu código que outros. Se você mudar os valores pra serem os mesmos, vai ver os mesmos erros nos dois ambientes (contanto que seja a mesma versão do PHP).

No seu caso específico um dos ambientes está reportando que uma (ou mais) das variáveis testadas não foi declarada anteriormente (`undefined index, índice não declarado`), o que é uma boa prática mas não é obrigatório. Isso não é um defeito (por isso o nível `NOTICE`, não `WARNING` ou `ERROR`).

Em geral servidores de desenvolvimento tem `display_errors = true` e ajusta-se o nível de `error_reporting` para o nível desejado.

Servidores de produção tem `display_errors = false` pra quem mesmo que um erro aconteça isso não necessariamente apareça para os seus visitantes (mas fique registrado no log visível pros desenvolvedores).

[**error_reporting**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-reporting.php)

[**display_errors**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

Comment: no caso só preciso alterar o error reporting, porém uma coisa que você mencionou é que ele não impede o funcionamento do aplicativo, neste caso, estes erros impedem o funcionamento, são partes sensíveis que fazem saber se o user está ou não logado e estes erros impedem de o aplicativo realizar as checagens, por exemplo.

mas vou configurar aqui e já retorno

Comment: tudo que tento alterar como por exemplo para Off ou False ou até mesmo o error_reporting(0); fazem o programa travar por completo

Comment: @flourigh essas configurações não tem o poder de travar o seu programa, a menos que a sintaxe esteja errada. Alguma outra coisa está causando isso. Experimente colocar error_reporting = E_ALL e display_errors = true e reinicie o apache/nginx antes de testar. Depois vá corrigindo todos os erros que aparecerem, um por um.

Comment: estou começando a pensar que seja erro do PHPDESKTOP algum tipo de BUG pois todas as opções que eu coloco no php.ini fazem o programa travar

Comment: ai que está, estou utilizando o PHPDESKTOP então pode ser que seja um BUG mas na wiki do github deles não achei nada

Comment: pois é, acho mesmo que seja um defeito no PHPDESKTOP pois no USBWEBSERVER eu desliguei o display_errors e funcionou normalmente já com ele ligado da o mesmo erro do PHPDESKTOP mas no USBWEBSERVER quando desliga funciona normal, já no PHPDESKTOP quando desliga o programa inteiro trava